# Подключение к Базе SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Доброго. Помогите найти привидение )

С# + SQL SERVER, пытаюсь подключиться. Стандартные настройки, Студия подключена к БД, да и обидно, на подключении сыпаться

```
string mybd_host = ".";
string mybd_name = "Awr2015";
string mybd_user = "";
string mybd_pass = "";
string connetionString = "Data Source=" + mybd_host + ";Initial Catalog=" + mybd_name + ";User ID=" + mybd_user + ";Password=" + mybd_pass + "";
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

try
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Open !");
        cnn.Open();//вот тут ошибка
        cnn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("connection:" + exp);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Can not open connection:" + ex);//mysql
}
```

Подключение проходит, Connection Open, но при открытии соединения, вылетает ошибка, Вызвано исключение: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll

т.е. доступ есть, но при открытии его доступа нету. Господа, поставьте на путь истинный, что исправить что бы открыть соединение с БД?

Comment: user и pass пустые, это нормально? Если Вы хотите подключаться c windows authentication то надо добавить к строке "Integrated Security= True"

Comment: Для получения Connection String лучше использовать SqlConnectionStringBuilder. И приведите текст исключения, одного типа исключения недостаточно для анализа проблемы.

Comment: экземпляр sql-сервера дефолтный или именованный? ну и как сказали ранее: нужен полный текст исключения.

Comment: @Aleksandr Zharinov - помогло! Что ж не в ответы?

Comment: @nzeemin - вариант буду иметь ввиду на след. проекты

Comment: Я не был уверен. Думал Вы просто скрываете свои учетные данные. Сейчас оформлю как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы хотите подключаться под учетной записью Windows, то необходимо в строку коннекции добавить опцию "Integration Security= True".
Кроме того, для конкатенации строк в целом и строк коннекции в частности лучше использовать специальные классы [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) и [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) соответственно.